# Accessing cloud kubenates services on local network

Tags: kubernetes, networking

Looking for a solution to enable access to services on a cloud-hosted Kubernetes cluster on local network for various developers without each machine having to use kubectl to port forward and actually have the access to the cluster.

Essentially looking for a way to run a docker container or vm which I can expose the ports or even better away to forward local network traffic to clusters dns.

Really stuck looking for solutions, any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What is the problem with kubectl port forward? What is the use case to expose the cluster services to many developers?

Comment: Avoid confusion for developers, prevent multiple ssh tunnels, avoid having to run kubectl, and keep it running on every machine. Consider this cloud-hosted development cluster. I care about it being secure from the internet but not the developers.

Sorry re-read your question, yes exactly! expose for multiple developers.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.telepresence.io/ or you might need to build something custom that forwards calls from dev machines to the cluster.

Comment: Could you please provide additional details for your question? Which type of access should have developers (permissions) and to what resources (deployed applications or APIs)?